# HTML code entered in textarea doesn't save in database

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular

So I have a section on my website where I write news posts. The Idea I had was to write these posts in HTML so that they are nice and pretty. Then I copy this HTML code and enter it inside a Textarea element. I then tried to save this input into my database on the Node.js back-end.

I checked the type of the textarea input with a `typeof text` and it returned 'string'. I thought I would now be able to send this to my back-end and save it in my database, but I noticed that `req.body` on the Node.js back-end is empty. SO something went wrong.

Does someone know a better way to do this?

**Console.log(text) in the component returns this (and typeof states that it's a string)**

```
<h1>This is a test</h1>
        <h2 class="test">Does it work or not?</h2>
        <img src="https://ep01.epimg.net/cultura/imagenes/2017/11/08/1up/1510164524_440393_1510165636_noticia_normal.jpg">
```

**addNews.component.ts**

```
export class AddNewsPostComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private newsService: LatestNewsService) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    saveHtmlNewsPost(text) {
        console.log(text);
        console.log(typeof text);
        this.newsService.saveNewsPost(text)
            .subscribe((data) => {
                console.log(data)
            })
    }
}
```

**addPost.component.html**

```
<textarea #htmlCode name="htmlCode" id="htmlCode" rows="30">

</textarea>
<button (click)="saveHtmlNewsPost(htmlCode.value)" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block">Add Markup to Database</button>



<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class=" col-md-10 sandBox">
        <h1>This is a test</h1>
        <h2 class="test">Does it work or not?</h2>
        <img src="https://ep01.epimg.net/cultura/imagenes/2017/11/08/1up/1510164524_440393_1510165636_noticia_normal.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

**news.service.ts**

```
saveNewsPost(text) {
        console.log(typeof text);
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/news/saveNewsPost', text)
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
    }
```

**news route on Node.js back-end (console.log(req.body) returns an empty object**

```
router.post('/saveNewsPost', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);

    var newPost = new NewsArticle({
        htmlCode: req.body
    });

    newPost.save(function(err, newsArticle){
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: "An error occurred",
                error: err
            })
        }
        res.status(200).json({
            message: "Succesfully saved the newsArticle",
            obj: newsArticle
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: Have you tried with: `<textarea [(ngModel)]='htmlCode'></textarea>`

Comment: Can you provide us a code for `this.newsService.saveNewsPost` service method? So far code looks fine

Comment: Can you post the code for `this.newsService.saveNewsPost()` and the endPoint that handles it.  Those seem like the most pertinent pieces to this puzzle as it's apparent your issue isn't with getting the value from the textarea.

Comment: I have added the service file and the node.js route to the original post

Comment: @RodrigoMata I have tried this, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Bind data properties to each form control using the ngModel two-way data-binding syntax.

See detailed description on.
https://angular.io/guide/forms.

Html

Component

```
 export class AddNewsPostComponent implements 
 OnInit 
  {

     htmlCode: string;
constructor(private newsService: LatestNewsService) {}

ngOnInit() {}

saveHtmlNewsPost() {
    console.log(this.htmlCode);
    console.log(typeof this.htmlCode);
    this.newsService.saveNewsPost(this.htmlCode)
        .subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data)
        })
}
```

}

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't change anything. Still the same error.

Comment: Then you need to set data type of posted html.  On backend nodeJs server, your bodyparser might creating issue with conversation of htmlCode